# Problem displaying maps .mpk files via LeafletJS and Laravel

Tags: leaflet, maps, geojson

I created a website with the Laravel framework. Then I want to display maps on the website using leafletJS, using a file with the extension .mpk (note = the mpk file contains maps of several regions and several symbols/legends).
However, leaflets cannot accept input in the form of mpk files, generally leaflets accept input with the geojson extension.

I tried to find a way to convert mpk files to geojson format, but failed (I don't have access to an application like ArcGIS). Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions regarding this problem?